# SQL datasets are not showing when trying to add data sources to Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Basically i'm trying to follow this step in a video here. https://youtu.be/QGYhwry-2rQ?t=236

I am trying to connect AdventureWorksDW2014 dataset to visual studio but the only options I have are master, model, msdb, and temdb. In the video I see all of that persons databases but I do not have any. Any help would be appreciated!

[Visual Studio trying to connect to database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLb5a.jpg)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? From my understanding the database is already created and it's stored in the SQL databases. I figured it would show up because I am using the 'sqlclient' data source.

Comment: Using the SQL Server Management Studio do you see the Database created?

Comment: Yes https://imgur.com/a/A8gcEXx

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have AdventureWorksDW2014  database installed in your database server

you need to download it and install it,

follow these steps to do so

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4168/install-your-own-copy-of-the-sql-server-adventureworks2014-database/